# How to add this jQuery library to my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've worked with JS a lot in school, but we never used libraries. There's so little info online as to how to succesfully add one with all the necessary external resources to a project.

I'm trying to add a library that uses jQuery to have a small window pop-up inside the page (http://jsfiddle.net/55DBx/1/) of a website I'm working on but no matter what I do, it doesn't work as it's supposed to. On jsFiddle, it says the library needs jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css which I've both linked to my HTML file as follows:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
<link rel="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

and I've added the sample code from jsFiddle to my project, and it doesn't work. The pop-up window's content just shows up directly on the page.

```html
<button id="btnExample">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Test">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>

<script>$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#btnExample" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});</script>
```

What am I missing? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may place the library references in wrong places, you should place them within the `<head></head>` section.
And in your css reference, you are adding the link for `rel` attribute, which is used for specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document/resource, you should add the link for `href` attribute.

```js
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#btnExample" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<button id="btnExample">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Randy">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sykonist/south-park/256/Randy-Marsh-Jamming-2-icon.png" />
</div>
```

The entire code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $("#btnExample").click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btnExample">open the dialog</button>
    <div id="dialog" title="Randy">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sykonist/south-park/256/Randy-Marsh-Jamming-2-icon.png" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I didn't have that line in my `<head>` : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` as it wasn't listed on jsFiddle. Is that just a standard line to add for anything using AJAX?

Comment: You are welcome. If this works for you, feel free to mark it as answer. 
Yes, if you are using AJAX, which is one of the jQuery API, you must need to add this library reference.